# Differences between lua 5.2 and 5.3 table libraries

Tags: lua

In the official Lua 5.3 documentation in multiple places talks about changes made to ipairs and the table standard library made in order to make them "respect metamethods," but I could not find any reference to specific changes or find code samples illustrating these differences. If anyone knows of any resources detailing the differences between versions that would be extremely helpful.

links:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html#changes

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly this is to respect `__len`, `__index`, and `__newindex`. Also `__ipairs` is no longer supported.

This may not be an complete list, it has been a while since I worked with 5.2 much...